# How to SELECT DISTINCT Info with TOP 1 Info and an Order By FROM the Top 1 Info

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables, that look like:

```
CustomerInfo(CustomterID, CustomerName)
CustomerReviews(ReviewID, CustomerID, Review, Score)
```

I want to search reviews for a string and return `CustomerInfo.CustomerID` and `CustomerInfo.CustomerName`. However, I only want to show distinct `CustomerID` and `CustomerName` along with just one of their `CustomerReviews.Reviews` and `CustomerReviews.Score`. I also want to order by the `CustomerReviews.Score`.

I can't figure out how to do this, since a customer can leave multiple reviews, but I only want a list of customers with their highest scored review.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to search Reviews for a string but bring back  that 
customer's highest scoring Review even if that itself doesn't match the string?

Comment: Is there a possibility that a customer might have more than one review with the same highest score value? And if so, do you want them all, or just one of them? And if just one of them, which one? ("I don't care" is not a valid option.)

Comment: Just one of them, but I would want that review to match the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the greatest-n-per-group problem that has come up dozens of times on Stack Overflow.

Here's a solution that works with a window function:

```
WITH CustomerCTE (
  SELECT i.*, r.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Score DESC) AS RN
  FROM CustomerInfo i
  INNER JOIN CustomerReviews r ON i.CustomerID = r.CustomerID 
  WHERE CONTAINS(r.Review, '"search"')
)
SELECT * FROM CustomerCTE WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Score;
```

And here's a solution that works more broadly with RDBMS brands that don't support window functions:

```
SELECT i.*, r1.*
FROM CustomerInfo i
INNER JOIN CustomerReviews r1 ON i.CustomerID = r1.CustomerID 
  AND CONTAINS(r1.Review, '"search"')
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerReviews r2 ON i.CustomerID = r2.CustomerID 
  AND CONTAINS(r1.Review, '"search"')
  AND (r1.Score < r2.Score OR r1.Score = r2.Score AND r1.ReviewID < r2.ReviewID)
WHERE r2.CustomerID IS NULL
ORDER BY Score;
```

I'm showing the [`CONTAINS()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) function because you should be using the fulltext search facility in SQL Server, not using `LIKE` with wildcards.

Comment: Thanks. I do have full text search enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot more sense, and seems like it works well performance wise. I do have full text enabled, and the "score" I was referring to is actually the "rank" from the full text search. I wasn't sure if many ppl are familiar with full text. I think I can replace "score" with "rank" and join the CONTAINSTABLE.

Answer (score 1):

I voted for Bill Karwin's answer, but I thought I'd throw out another option.

It uses a [correlated subquery](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3485291/Using-a-Correlated-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm), which can often incur performance problems with large data sets, so use with caution.  I think the only upside is that the query is easier to immediately understand.

```
select *
from [CustomerReviews] r
where [ReviewID] =
(
    select top 1 [ReviewID]
    from [CustomerReviews] rInner
    where rInner.CustomerID = r.CustomerID
    order by Score desc
)
order by Score desc
```

I didn't add the string search filter, but that can be easily added.

Comment: Yeah but I try to avoid correlated subqueries if there's another solution that's not correlated.  The other solution is *usually* more efficient (there's an exception to every rule, though).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it

```
select ci.CustomterID, ci.CustomerName, cr.Review, cr.Score
from CustomerInfo ci inner join 
(select top 1*
from CustomerReviews
where Review like '%search%'
order by Score desc) cr on ci.CustomterID = cr.CustomterID 
order by cr.Score
```

Comment: Is there a faster query? This seems like it would be very slow with a lot of records since I'll be performing an individual search for each customer record.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont know any other way, have check the query's execution plan?